# Accessing previously attached files in visual workflow

Tags: attachment, visual-workflow

I'm using the Visual Cloud Workflow Designer to build a flow that will help users work cases.  I need to provide them with access to the files already attached to the case they're currently working from within the flow.

Has anyone found a way to do this?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, the only way you could do this is to embed your flow in a Visualforce page, which would then have to contain a controller to retrieve and display those attachments.

Theoretically, it MAY be possible to generate links to attachments by making a Dynamic Choice, but you'd have to adjust the Choice Label to include the full URL, which would be difficult, and I'm not sure you could make it render as HTML either.